# In Android---Gmail OAuthentication not open the Gmail SignIn page

Tags: android

In Android How can i Use Gmail OAuthentication.
I import sample code from the github svn but Not open gmail Sign in page.

[Svn Rep](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidOAuthFlowSample.git)
(I also add 3 jar file signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar,signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar,signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar)

Its not contain error but when i open apps then its display

```
Responce status : Unauthorized.
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below link code.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

It work great.(Not contain Unauthorized error).

Thanks.